# Get shell variable value by string concatenation - POSIX

Tags: shell

I want to retrieve specific variable values depending on 'prod' or 'dev' environment, without chaining lots of if-else blocks with the same content.
Therefore, I have the variables like this:

```sh
prod_key=daksjhdkjasd
dev_key=kajsdnaskldk
```

I want to evaluate the correct key in some way like this:

```sh
env=prod

key=${env}_key
```

Of course I've tried the above and it didn't work, just replaced the 'env' variable.
(I'm using dash (/bin/sh))

Comment: You are interested in indirection (See [BashFAQ 006](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection)). Indirection is not part of POSIX but can be _mimicked_ using `eval` with all its consequences.

Comment: The link you provided a minute ago had the answer! I did this `eval \"\${${env}_key}\"` and it worked..  Ugly, but it works. I'm not concerned about security here either.  Thank you!